# Gitlab ldap only working with user as base

Tags: ldap, gitlab

I set up a gitlab server and want to connect it to our AD.
If I set the `base` of the config to an AD user it works fine and this user can log in via LDAP.
If I set `base` to an AD group so all users can log in, it does not work.
I get the following error:

```
Could not authorize you from Ldapmain because "Invalid credentials".
```

`gitlab-rake gitlab:ldap:check` returns:

```
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rouge-1.9.1/lib/roug/lexers/shell.rb:20: warning: already initialized constant Rouge::Lexers::Shell::KEYWORDS
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rouge-1.9.1/libroug/lexers/shell.rb:20: warning: previous definition of KEYWORDS was here/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rouge-1.9.1/lib/rouge/lexers/shell.rb:25: warning: already initialized constant Rouge::Lexers::Shell::BUILTINS
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rouge-1.9.1/lib/rouge/lexers/shell.rb:25: warning: previous definition of BUILTINS was here
Checking LDAP ...

LDAP users with access to your GitLab server (only showing the first 100 results)
Server: ldapmain
DN: CN=XXX,OU=Security Groups,OU=MyBusiness,DC=XXX,DC=local   sAMAccountName: XXX

Checking LDAP ... Finished
```

Any ideas why it does not work with a group?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more details on your exact configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `base`-entry sets the base in the LDAP-tree where to start looking for users. So if your users are located in `OU=Users,OU=MyBusiness,DC=XXX,DC=local` you need to set that as base. You can also set `DC=XXX,DC=local` as base and everyone "below" that entry will be able to log into your gitlab instance. But if you set `OU=Groups,OU=MyBusiness,DC=XXX,DC=local` as base and there are no users "below" that base no one will be able to log into gitlab as the LDAP-server can't find any users.